# Python search, listing and selected printing

Tags: python

I have a file which contains several energies from an organic molecule.
I want to make a python script which allows me to print a selected energy, lets say the first one or the second one or the last one or the third before the last, etc etc.
I am learning python, and I understand I should made a list of the searching, insert a second argument which indicates which energy I want to print. Since I am learning I am not sure how to do this. Here are the scripts I have made, but the first one just print the first energy, and the second script just prints the last one. Any help is highly appreciated. (Here is a link with an example of the files that I am using as an input https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63216126/ActCat.out)

First code I made

```
    import sys
    import re

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    newfile = str(filename) + ".3d"

    openold = open(filename,"r")
    opennew = open(newfile,"w")


    rline = openold.readlines()

    for line in rline:
        if re.search( r"SCF Done", line ):
            words = line.split()

            energy = float( words[4] )

            print >>opennew,  "The energy of the molecule is %f kcal mol-1" % energy
            break

    openold.close()
    opennew.close()
```

Second code I made

```
    import sys
    import re


    filename = sys.argv[1]
    newfile = str(filename) + ".3d"

    openold = open(filename,"r")
    opennew = open(newfile,"w")

    start = 0

    rline = openold.readlines()

    for i in range (len(rline)):
        if "SCF Done" in rline[i]:
            start = i

    for line in rline[start:start+1] :
        words = line.split()
        energy = words[4]
        print >>opennew,  "The energy of the molecule is %s kcal mol-1" % energy
        break


    openold.close()
    opennew.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to selectively choose which energy to print? This will gather all energies into a list, and then you can index into that list to print the one you want. Note that I removed the `break` from the loop so it gathers all of them.

```
import sys
import re

filename = sys.argv[1]
newfile = str(filename) + ".3d"

openold = open(filename,"r")
opennew = open(newfile,"w")


rline = openold.readlines()
energies = []
line_number = 0
for line in rline:
    line_number += 1
    if re.search( r"SCF Done", line ):
        words = line.split()

        energy = float( words[4] )
        energies.append(("The energy of the molecule is %f kcal mol-1" % energy, line_number))

print >>opennew, energies[0] # print first energy and line number
print >>opennew, energies[4] # print 5th energy and line number
print >>opennew, energies[-1] # print last energy and line number
print energies[1][0] # print energy
print energies[1][1] # print line number

openold.close()
opennew.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh, that is very helpful.
However, I still have one more question, is there any way to know and print the line number (in the length of the file) in which the particular energy I am printing is.